# Adding Multipoint Features to ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online

I was attempting to upload a zipped multipoint shapefile to AGO when I received this error:"Unable to import this shapefile. (Unable to get property 'intersects' of undefined or null reference)". I was unsure why I got the error but I noticed that AGO states at this time it does not support multipoint shapefiles. So is there some other format besides a .shp that you can upload a multipoint feature like a gdb feature class or an SDE layer or is it a no go all together.

Comment: I just want to add that the data was able to be uploaded to AGO as a multipoint geometry type. That being said I don't want to close the question because I don't know exactly how or in what data format this was accomplished, I ended up handing it over to our GIS librarian who put it onto our SDE server and they uploaded it.